# TypeCasting Struct and Classes

Tags: c++, class, casting

I am very new to C++. Currently I am reviewing a source code where I saw some typecasting, but I didn't understand it.
Here is the code.

```
struct str {
    char *a;
    int b;
};

class F {
public:
    char* val;
};  

F f1;
```

Can anyone explain the below Assignement Please.or is that typecasting valid??

```
 str* ptr = (str*) f1->val;
```

Comment: Probably not, possibly yes. Can't tell without more info.

Comment: If you're very new to C++ you shouldn't be messing around with type casting. Especially this one, which looks bogus.

Comment: you're just cast a char* to a str*, it's not valid in theory or in practice because ptr->b will be pointing outside of F into some unknown memory space.

Comment: Just to clarify the operator precedence, this is equivalent to `str* ptr = (str*) (f1->val);`

Comment: You should check the code you posted. It's invalid and should not compile at all because it's using `->` on `f1` which is not a pointer (nor declares an `operator ->`). Also you should format your code better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone explain the below Assignement Please.

It means "pretend that the `val` pointer points to an object of type `str`, even though it's declared to point to a completely different type `char`; give me that pointer and trust that I know what I'm doing".

That's assuming that the real code either declares `F * f1;`, or accesses it as `f1.val`; the code you've posted won't compile.

> or is that typecasting valid??

**If** the pointer really does point to an object of the correct type, then it's valid; otherwise, using the pointer will cause the program to fail in all sorts of catastrophic ways.

Typecasting is something that should very rarely be necessary. If you really do need it, you should never (as in absolutely never, under any circumstances) use that C-style cast; it means "force the conversion with no checks whatsoever, as long as there's some way to do it, even if it makes absolutely no sense". Use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` when you can, and `reinterpret_cast` or `const_cast` when you're doing something really dodgy. And don't use any of them unless you know what you're doing, and have a very good reason for circumventing the type system.

Comment: Note that for a standard-layout class, a pointer to an object can be safely converted to a pointer to the first member.

Comment: @KerrekSB: True, but that's not what's happening here.

Comment: Oh, sorry -- that comment would have made more sense if `str::a` was a `char`. Never mind.